# What unicode characters are suitable for making a heatmap in console?

Tags: unicode, console, heatmap

I want to make a command that takes a matrix or vectors of numbers and prints a string-representation where every number is mapped to a character with varying darkness depending on its value.

The only characters I've found that gives a consistent shape but varying color is the unicode block elements ' ░▒▓█' (see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements#Compact_table)), but this only gives me 5 possible shades (space, 3 shades, 1 filled block). I use every character twice so the widhts is approximately the same as the height.

What other characters are suitable for drawing a heatmap in console?

See example code in python below. The question is of course applicable for other languages as well.

```py
import numpy as np

def ascii_heatmap(matrix: np.ndarray, disp=True):
    assert matrix.ndim <= 2
    matrix = np.atleast_2d(matrix)
    vmax = matrix.max()
    vmin = matrix.min()
    symbolrange= ' ░▒▓█'
    symbol_index_matrix = (matrix - vmin) * (len(symbolrange)-1) / (vmax-vmin)
    heatmap_rows = []
    for row in symbol_index_matrix:
        heatmap_rows.append("".join(map(lambda x: symbolrange[int(x)]*2, row)))
    heatmap = "\n".join(heatmap_rows)
    if disp==True:
        print(heatmap)
    return heatmap

#Examples with vector and matrix
ascii_heatmap(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
ascii_heatmap(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [turbo ramp](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/turbo-improved-rainbow-colormap-for.html) ([Python code](https://gist.github.com/mikhailov-work/ee72ba4191942acecc03fe6da94fc73f)) and [true colour terminal](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728) output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $step = 17;
for (my $r = 0; $r <= 255; $r += $step) {
    for (my $g = 0; $g <= 255; $g += $step) {
        for (my $b = 0; $b <= 255; $b += $step) {
            print "\e[48;2;$r;$g;${b}m ";
            #       ↑ escape char     ↑ coloured space char
        }
    }
}
```